# What is the name of the start screen executable?

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

It just stopped running and I want to know how to restart it w/o logging out and in...

Answer (score 3):

It is explorer.exe.   If you have task manager open (you can start it from the ctrl+alt+del menu), do File -> run new task and type explorer.   This got me a regular explorer window, in there, go to c:\windows\ and run explorer.exe -- this brought the start screen and charms back for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a separate executable, but rather built-in into your desktop...

Just press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, or hover your mouse in the bottom left corner.

Comment: Hmm. I got to a state that the windows key did nothing and the edges brought up nothing. How do I restart the desktop then? I tried killing explorer and restarting it and no cigar.

Comment: Did you apply any anti-start screen patch? Because this is weird...

Comment: Nope. Nothing like that. So far happened only once.. So in what process does this actually live? Does anyone know? It must live somewhere in user session land.

Comment: @ShaharPrish: Okay, I'll just suppose I was wrong above. Let's suppose this to be `explorer.exe`, then killing `explorer.exe` would no longer allow you to press the start button if my assumption were right. That might mean that restarting `explorer.exe` could solve your problem; in which case, I apologize and it appears this is not implemented in the parent of `explorer.exe` (`wininit.exe`?) but in `explorer.exe` itself. I also doubt you would be able to restart the parent process, as that is the desktop itself. So, if restarting `explorer.exe` doesn't help, there is not much you can do...

Comment: Thanks. Was a bit hard to compile what you said, but I think I got it. Essentially SOL. :) Ah well. That kind'a sucks.